# Why the type changes when MUI Select is styled

Tags: material-ui

I want to customize and use MUI Select.

```
import { SelectProps, Select, styled } from "@mui/material";
export const CustomizeSelect = styled(Select)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-error": {
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderWidth: "3px",
    },
  },
}))
```

Usage sample.

```
<CustomizeSelect native onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}>
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</CustomizeSelect>
```

Here comes the problem.

When using MUI Select, onChange is `e: SelectChangeEvent<string>`, but when using CustomizeSelect, it becomes `e: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>`.

I don't understand why it's unknown.
This is because it did not occur with TextField that was used with Customize in the same way.

---

Usage version.

- "@mui/material": "^5.13.7"
- "react": "^18.2.0"
- "typescript": "^5.1.6"

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing.